# Why is the mitzvah of Shofar on Rosh Hashannah for hearing the sound and not for blowing the shofar?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

There is no direct mitzvah to blow the shofar on Rosh Hashanna. The mitzvah is to hear the shofar blown. It seems that this mitzvah is phrased "causativly". In order to hear the sound, someone has to blow it! Yet, the blower doesn't get any direct mitzvah for the act of blowing; he "passively" gets the mitzvah when he hears his own blowing.

Why is there no mitzvah for actively doing the blowing itself? As for those that cannot blow, technically, they could fulfill the obligation by someone else doing it, no? Wouldn't that work the same way as someone making Kiddush for another?

Comment: You have given no reason to suspect there should be such a Mitzva, so this is a pretty weak question. Most Mitzvot have actions which need to be done prior to the Mitzva (eg. building a Sukkah, baking Matza)

Comment: It is not like Kiddush. It's like Tefillin. I can't put Tefillin on for you as it is a Mitzva shebeGufo, a commandment pertaining to your body.

Comment: Guesswork: We don't have any Mitzvot that each individual must do himself that require a skill that not everybody has. Since many people are not capable of blowing a Shofar properly, it's "not fair" to require each & every Jew to blow the Shofar by themselves. (But again, this is a guess, I have no proof of this idea. Yet.)

Comment: @Danny How is a women supposed to get a mezuza?

Comment: @DoubleAA - precisely my point. She can ask somebody to write it and to affix it. There's no Mitzva to write one by yourself - since it requires special skills.

Comment: @DannySchoemann She _can't_ write one herself. That doesn't seem fair to require someone to do something which they cannot do. Incidentally there is a Mitzva to write a Torah scroll. What about a one armed person donning Tefillin?

Comment: @DoubleAA - she doesn't have to write one herself. She can go buy one. Same with writing a Sefer Torah - you can do the Mitzva by paying somebody to write it for you. All the jibes with my guess/theory that there are no Mitzvot that each individual must do by themselves that require special skills. (One armed and Tefillin is already in the area of אונס רחמנא פטריה I would imagine.) IOW the Torah assumes we won't be stranded alone on a desert island.

Comment: The mitzvah is also to *hear* the megillah (not to read it), to *sit in* the sukkah (not to build it), to *eat kosher meat* (if eating meat) but not to *slaughter* it.  I don't know how large a category this is, but I wouldn't automatically assume the mitzvah *should* be for the blowing and not the hearing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio and yet for  Megilla we say "al mikra Megilla" but for shofar "liahmoa kol shofar".....

Comment: Do you want to know how do we know, or truly why?

Comment: @andrewmh20, speak for yourself. MonicaCellio presumably says "_lishmoa (mikra) m'gila_", as other women do.

Answer (score -2):

it's the same as needing to build a sukkah althhough there's no mitzvah for it in order to eat in eat which is a mitzvah
yes someone could blow for another

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Good try :-) but the question is just that; there's no Mitzva to build a Sukka, but rather to sit in it. But the Torah says (or does it?) that it's a day to BLOW shofar.